# how to fix java.lang.arrayindexoutofboundsexception: 0?

Tags: java

I'm a newbie to `java`. Can anyone pls help me with resolving the error `arrayindexoutofboundsexception`.

```
public class Minesweeper { 
   public static void main(String[] args) { 

      int M = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
      int N = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
      double p = Double.parseDouble(args[2]);

      // game grid is [1..M][1..N], border is used to handle boundary cases
      boolean[][] bombs = new boolean[M+2][N+2];
      for (int i = 1; i <= M; i++)
         for (int j = 1; j <= N; j++)
            bombs[i][j] = (Math.random() < p);

      // print game
      for (int i = 1; i <= M; i++) {
         for (int j = 1; j <= N; j++)
            if (bombs[i][j]) System.out.print("* ");
            else             System.out.print(". ");
         System.out.println();
      }

      // sol[i][j] = # bombs adjacent to cell (i, j)
      int[][] sol = new int[M+2][N+2];
      for (int i = 1; i <= M; i++)
         for (int j = 1; j <= N; j++)
            // (ii, jj) indexes neighboring cells
            for (int ii = i - 1; ii <= i + 1; ii++)
               for (int jj = j - 1; jj <= j + 1; jj++)
                  if (bombs[ii][jj]) sol[i][j]++;

      // print solution
      System.out.println();
      for (int i = 1; i <= M; i++) {
         for (int j = 1; j <= N; j++)
            if (bombs[i][j]) System.out.print("* ");
            else             System.out.print(sol[i][j] + " ");
         System.out.println();
      }

   }
}
```

and here is the exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0 at Minesweeper.main(Minesweeper.java:5)
```

Comment: by not using index 0 when there is no such element?

Comment: I get the exception as Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
 at Minesweeper.main(Minesweeper.java:5) @Jens

Comment: @user26 Your Array index will start from 0 and will end at M-1 or N-1

Comment: There is no args[0] - that is the only 0 index you use! The others should be 0 based, but will work as you allocate an extra space at the end.

Comment: @user26 time to accept the answer and close it.

Answer (score 9):

Two things probably as it says index 0 (see first case for the same):

1. You are not passing arguments to your main class.
2. Array index always start from 0 and not 1. So you might need to change either:

   - your loop to start with 0 and check i < M or N
   - You use array index as i - 1 instead of i.

Reason you are getting ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException is lets say you have 2 elements in an array. It will be as below:

```
a[0] = 1;
a[1] = 2;
```

And when you are looping using i = 1; i<=2 you are accessing:

```
a[1] - which is perfect
a[2] - which was not expected?
```

Comment: Everyone else forgot about passing arguments :)

Comment: I did not and [here is my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26618493/3128926):) I even put screen captures of eclipse for how to use command-line arguments with run configurations.

Comment: In my case I wasn't passing arguments because I accidentally dropped a line continuation while editing a long bash command that called my main class. :(

Answer (score 5):

You have to check the length of the array `args` before accessing an element. Since you have to access 2nd element in the array, the lengh should be atleast 3. You have to check that like below

```
if(args.length > 2) {
  //wrap all code here
}
```

Comment: I would rather use a defensive short `if (args.length < 3)`, and put an error message and a `return;` inside. Wrapping the whole method body is IMO an over-indentation.

Answer (score 4):

**(SOLUTION #1)**

You have used the command line arguments as below, args[0], args[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iFMFI.png) and args[3] means your class need 3 parameters in order to run correctly however you've provided no parameters thus,

```
//      int M = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
//      int N = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
//      double p = Double.parseDouble(args[2]);

        int M = 2;
        int N = 3;
        double p = 3.99;
```

Then your code output will be;

```
* * * 
* * * 

* * * 
* * *
```

Your code needs 3 parameters and what I've done above is just assigning those parameters with assignment instead of using the values of args[] array.

**(SOLUTION #2)**

Instead of changing your code, you can pass 3 command-line arguments which stands for int M, N and double p. To do this in **eclipse** ide;

1. Right click to your class and select run as -> run configurations ;

[image]

2. Select the arguments tab and write your three parameters leaving space in between of them ;

[image]

Now you won't get "**ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException**" again, with values 2 4 0.9, the output will be;

```
* * . * 
* . * * 

* * 4 * 
* 4 * *
```

**(EXPLANATION)**

There are two problem in your code;

1. You have the **ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException** exception which means your code tries to reach an array value with an exceeding index.
2. You are using command line arguments but you are not entering any arguments as a parameter. Your main method needs 3 parameters in order to run correctly but with no parameters. `args[0]`, `args[1]` and `args[2]` means there is an array names with args[] and you are trying to reach 0th, 1st and 2nd elements of the args[] array. However, if you provide no command-line parameter, you are trying to reach a null value and thus you get;

   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
       at com.stack1.Minesweeper.main(Minesweeper.java:8)

To make it clear, first I will explain what is **ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException**;

**ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException** error occurs when a statement in your code tries to reach an array index where the index is greater than the length of the array. Let me explain this;

Assume that you have 2 cars. The color of your **first car** is **red**, and the color of your **second car** is **blue**. If I ask you that "what's your second car's color" , you will return me the answer as blue. But what is I ask "what's your fifth car's color?" what you will say is "I don't own a fifth car".

"**ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException**" error is the same, in this case, you just return an "**ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException**" error because the index 5 is greater than the maximum count of your car indexes, which actually the length of the car array.

```
String car[] = new String[2];

car[0] = "blue";
car[1] = "red";
```

To make it clear, let's run the code below;

```
public class CarColorExample
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String[] carArray = new String[2];

        carArray[0] = "blue";
        carArray[1] = "red";

        System.out.println("1st car color value: " + carArray[0]);
        System.out.println("2nd car color value: " + carArray[1]);
        System.out.println("3rd car color value: " + carArray[2]);
    }

}
```

If you try and run the code above, you will get the exception as below;

```
1st car color value: blue
2nd car color value: red

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2
    at com.stack1.CarColorExample.main(CarColorExample.java:15)
```

There is the statement **"java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2"** which actually points to the exceeding index tells you that the carArray does not have a second index.

```
index: 0 --> "blue"
index: 1 --> "red"
index: 2 --> ????
```

As a second example about the **ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException** error, just check out the code below and run it;

```
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int[] intArray = new int[3];

        intArray[0] = 25;
        intArray[1] = 36;
        intArray[2] = 99;

        //Will work with no error
        for(int i = 0; i < intArray.length; i++)
            System.out.println("index[" + i + "], value:" + intArray[i]);

        //      Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3
        //          at com.stack1.ErrorExample2.main(ErrorExample2.java:18)
        //
        //      "ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException" error will occur for index: 3
        //      The length of the array is 2
        //      index: 0 --> 25
        //      index: 1 --> 36
        //      index: 2 --> 99
        //      There is no third index, That's all
        for(int i = 0; i < intArray.length + 1; i++)
            System.out.println("index[" + i + "], value:" + intArray[i]);
    }

}
```

Same problem in here, index '3', exceeds the maximum index of the array which is exactly stored in "intArray.length"

Answer (score 3):

You have to check if there is two args or not, with a code like this:

```
if(args.length > 2)
```

Also I think it is better to change lines like this :

```
for (int i = 1; i <= M; i++) {
 for (int j = 1; j <= N; j++)
```

to this:

```
for (int i = 0; i <M; i++) {
 for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
```

Comment: Regarding the `for` loops, the code over-allocates memory: `new boolean[M+2][N+2];`, therefore although bad practise, it is not an error in this case.