# Not sure why my java program isn't working

Tags: java, arrays

```
public class HelloName { 
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("Hello " + args[0] +"!");
        System.out.println("How are you?");
    }
}
```

When I run this program, Eclipse tells me this:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
>       at HelloName.main(HelloName.java:3)

Comment: [Javascript is not Java.](http://javascriptisnotjava.io/)

Comment: `args` is the list of commandline arguments being passed to your program. So `java HelloName foo bar` is getting two arguments, `foo` and `bar`. If you run it just `java HelloName` you will get that exception since you are looking for the first argument in a list that doesn't exist.

Comment: [This answer on the linked question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26618493/217324) shows how to specify command-line arguments to Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

You are not passing any parameters when executing your program, therefore `args` has length 0 so that's why you get `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` when accessing first element of this array (because there is none).

So you should execute your program like `java  HelloName hello`

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to access the first argument passed to the program and you are not sending anything. If you try and run your program with command line, that is `java HelloName Guilherme`, it will do what you want to do.

To do it in elcipse, check out [this link](http://theopentutorials.com/post/uncategorized/how-to-pass-command-line-arguments-in-eclipse-ide/).

Answer (score 0):

you have to run it with command arguments:

java HelloName argument0

Answer (score 0):

Are you making sure to put an argument into the main method? Because if you don't, it will through this exception because it is an empty array.